# How to send Message from ESB's topic to Message broker's Queue

Tags: wso2, message-queue, messagebroker, wso2-esb

I have created topic in ESB, which is subscribed by the proxy created in ESB. In my proxy i have provided the endpoint of queue that i have made in WSO2 Message broker. So when i publish message in my queue that is being subscribed by proxy the message should go to the queue of MB but this is not happening. What should i do to achieve this? My proxy code is:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CNN" transports="http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATE" value="message is sent to queue"/>
         </log>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="jms:/CNN?&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

What should i do so that when i publish my message in topic it should be visible in Message brokers queue?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post has details on how to use topics.

http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2012/07/wso2-esb-topic-tutorial-for-beginners.html?q=topic

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shelan. I have gone through this blog but still i dont get the purpose of esb's Topics. now i am going through this link :http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/2012/06/publishing-messages-message-broker-using-event-mediator. but again i am struck on this link as my MB Version2.0.0 doesn't support MessageBox. So What is its alternative?Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes second link is outdated with new product. Use this documentation http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/MB201/Integrating+WSO2+ESB and refer the section "Integrate Using Message Stores And Processors "

Comment: Earlier topics were used to pub-sub with WS eventing. But it is no longer in WSO2 MB and a removed feature form that product.

Comment: i have another question. can you provide me solution to this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872283/how-and-where-i-can-use-message-store-and-message-processor-in-esb.Thanks in advance