# How and where i can use message store and message processor in ESB?

Tags: jms, wso2, messagebroker, wso2-esb

I have used two instances of WSO2 ESB 4.6 at port number 9443(esb1) and 9446(esb2) and also using Message Broker 2.0.1 at 9444. I am using this url to perform my task :http://wso2.org/library/articles/2013/03/configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker. I have done the Queue to queue send recieve example using the above link. And everything is working fine. But the problem is when i post any message to esb1, it gets reflected to esb2 since esb2 is working as my subscriber. I want that message store should store that message passed on from esb1 and based on some event it should provide esb2 the messages sent by esb1.
Thanks in advance.
When i make my Massage processor active i keep getting this error continuously :

```
[2013-04-08 17:58:56,658] ERROR - JobRunShell Job synapse.message.processor.quartz.Processor2-forward job threw an unhan
dled Exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.util.JMSUtil.createConnection(JMSUtil.java:46)
        at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.createConnection(JMSMessageStore.java:577)
        at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.getReadConnection(JMSMessageStore.java:517)
        at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.peek(JMSMessageStore.java:239)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.processors.forward.ForwardingJob.execute(ForwardingJob.java:88)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
[2013-04-08 17:58:56,669] ERROR - ErrorLogger Job (synapse.message.processor.quartz.Processor2-forward job threw an exce
ption.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:224)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.util.JMSUtil.createConnection(JMSUtil.java:46)
        at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.createConnection(JMSMessageStore.java:577)
        at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.getReadConnection(JMSMessageStore.java:517)
        at org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore.peek(JMSMessageStore.java:239)
        at org.apache.synapse.message.processors.forward.ForwardingJob.execute(ForwardingJob.java:88)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's some issue in your jndi.properties configuration. Make sure the connection factory configuration is valid which seems to have caused the reported issue. In message store implementation, the value of "connection factory" parameter defaults to "QueueConnectionFactory". If you're trying to specify another connection factory with a different name removing the default one (QueueConnectionFactory) from the configuration, make sure you specify the proper connection factory name in the appropriate element of the message store configuration.

Hope this helps!